# SharePoint Web Service Documentation?

Tags: sharepoint

Does anyone know where I can get documentation on "Lists Web Service" for SharePoint. I tried this link, but it seems that every child link goes to a random page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587198(office.11).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.aspx

Comment: Yea, that's what I was looking for.